# Unobtrusive JavaScript on a series of buttons

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm looking into [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), suggesting the JavaScript should be separated from HTML.

In my page, I use `jQuery 1.9.1` with `jQuery Migrate plugin 1.1.1` . I use `<li>` to simulate menu for my page. For each `<li>`, it is a menu item. Originally I assigned the JavaScript as follow:

```
    <ul>
        <li onclick="showQ('0001')">Q 1</li>
        <li onclick="showQ('0002')">Q 2</li>
        <li onclick="showQ('0003')">Q 3</li>
        <li onclick="showQ('0004')">Q 4</li>
    </ul>
```

**1st Question:** How to convert it with respective to Unobtrusive JavaScript ?

The JavaScript function is as follow:

```
function showQ(id) {
  $('#' + id).show();
}
```

**2nd Question:** ( it's probably a jQuery question ) How can the function reference the original `<li>`, e.g. to add a class via `.addClass('some_css_class');` ?

Comment: 'How to convert it with respective to Unobtrusive JavaScript ?' - what do you mean ? 'how can the function reference the original <li>, e.g. to add a class via .. ' - when to reference - on clicking any `li` ?

Comment: when `onclick` the `<li>`, the JS function `showQ` will execute. I want the `showQ` function to modify the `<li>` to add a custom CSS class on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `id` of each `<li>` to include the id that you want to pass into the `showQ` function. in the document ready handler assign a click hander to the `<li>` elements and call the `showQ` function from there, passing in the id extracted from the clicked `<li>`. in the click handler refer to the clicked `<li>` using `$(this)` in order to add a class to it

html

```
<ul>
    <li id="i0001">Q 1</li>
    <li id="i0002">Q 2</li>
    <li id="i0003">Q 3</li>
    <li id="i0004">Q 4</li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
function showQ(id) {
  $('#' + id).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id").substring(1);
        showQ(id);

        $(this).addClass("some_css_clas");
    });
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/HrDUj)

Comment: But the ids you've added to the li elements are duplicates of the ids used by the elements that `showQ()` shows. Better to use `data-associated-id="i0001"` or similar.

Comment: @nnnnnn is the `data-associated-id` valid in HTML5 ? or is it a proprietary properties ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - HTML5 allows you to add custom `data-` attributes, where you can put whatever you like after the `data-` part and it will be valid.

Comment: I end up using this answer with `data-associated-id` in replace of `id` of `<li>`. Thanks both !

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Q 1</li>
    <li>Q 2</li>
    <li>Q 3</li>
    <li>Q 4</li>
</ul>
```

JS snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('ul li').click(function(){


$(this).addClass('some_css_class');

});
```

});

**EDIT :**
In your function code:

```
function showQ(id) {
  $('#' + id).show();
}
```

which `id` do you want to show ? If the `li` with that `id` was not visible, how could you click on that ?

Comment: click on a `<li>` to show a `<div>`, which is initially hidden

Comment: no mentioning of `div` in the HTML in the OP. a bit more clarification please .